# Wildcard select of columns

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to select the columns that match a pattern?

For example, I would like to write something similar to `select customer_* from tbl` to select only the columns `customer_name`, `customer_age`, and `customer_height` from `tbl`

Comment: No, it is not. You might be able to write a function to compose a dynamic SQL query but nothing simpler. What would even be the order of the columns if such was possible?

Comment: Ok thanks. Why is column ordering a problem here? Theoretically, it could return columns in the same order that `select *` returns columns.