# select multiple columns in PostgreSQL using wildcard characters

Tags: sql, postgresql

It is possible to substitute a statement like this

```
select column1,column2,column3
```

with something like

```
select like 'column_'
```

in a Postgresql query?

Comment: Not using regular SQL.

Comment: It can be done using dynamic SQL. But why? Seems like an odd design decision to depend on column names.

Comment: was answered on SO I believe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres Dynamic Query Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639963/postgres-dynamic-query-function)

Comment: It was only a curiosity. Today it's my first day in sql. Thanx

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742536/wildcard-select-of-columns

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use `LIKE` in the `SELECT` part of the query.

Wildcards can only be used in the `WHERE` part of the query.